# mysql show items that are not matched in second table.

Tags: mysql

I believe i understand joins, left, right innner but I am having a problem with this task.  I have to show records that dont match in the second table.

Like if you are an employee, and the employee_phone table doesn't have a record matching you, what sort of query should I use?

I need to find all the employees who don't have a match in the employee_phone table.

Comment: God I love this site..  thanks to both of you who answered.   problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from employee
where id not in (select emp_id from employee_phone)
```

or

```
select e.* 
from employee e
left outer join employee_phone ep on e.id = ep.emp_id
where ep.emp_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

query will look like this if you only want to show record that has no match on the other table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45cad/2)

Answer (score 1):

select * from employees e where not exists (select 'x' from employee_phone ep where e.emp_id = ep.emp_id );

Basicly you want to do a not exists search in the employee_phone table joining them with the employee id (or other joining factor)

Need more information on the table structures to make it more accurate